# printing to console using ostream and operator <<

Tags: c++, g++

In an old project code was a statement like:

```
cout.operator<<("Hi...");    
ostream.operator<<("Hi....");
```

It argued that it can be written as followa, resulting in same output:

```
cout << "Hi..";
```

I have tried to put these statement in main(). But compiler gives error:

```
In function 'int main()':
11:3: error: 'ostream' was not declared in this scope
11:3: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/iosfwd:136:33: note:   'std::ostream'
   typedef basic_ostream<char>   ostream;
```

The other thing that I am not convinced of is this statement that ostream can directly call **operator<<**. Same about **cout** that can it call **operator<<** directly.

If some body could elaborate or explain how, then I will able to debug the code.
Thanks.

Comment: can you [edit] your post to show the main function & includes?

Comment: The error message is that there is no variable named `ostream`.  Change the second line to `cout.operator<<("Hi....");` or `static_cast<ostream&>(cout).operator<<("Hi....");`.

Answer (score 0):

The code line in question can actually ber compiled and does work, e.g:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    cout << "Hi"; // code line in question

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The quoted error is caused by using `ostream`, which is the type of `cout`, in a place where an object (not a type) is required.
As also mentioned in a comment, the fix of that error is using an object of that type instead. Which basically means the first line of quoted code, i.e. the line in the solution code above.